# Add a line to a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm working on homework have a question. The assignment has me adding a private attribute (private string history) which is supposed to be read/write. I can do all that. Then the instructions say "Make sure it can't be over-written - writing to it should add a line to the string."

How do I add a line to the string without overwriting anything?

Comment: Guys, he's not asking anyone to do his homework. Asking for how to append a line is helping him solve one piece.

Comment: @SonerGönül That's a ridiculously non-constructive comment. Either say what's wrong with the OP's **question** (not his motivation for asking it), or vote and move on, don't just yell something useless. (Especially at new users.)

Comment: I think he's asking because the instructions (as he is presenting them) are contradictory.  Oh, and I think you mean "private field", not "private attribute".

Comment: @Joel, **Environment.NewLine** may prove useful for you to know. Also, you might consider storing user inputs unmodified in a **List**, and then put them together when needed, perhaps using a **StringBuilder**. Each of these are terms you can find a lot more information on how to use via your favorite search engine. Happy coding.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a badly phrased question. You're right: a variable can't change its state yet simultaneously keep its state. I'm guessing they mean something like this:

```
    private string _SafeString;
    public string SafeString
    {
        get { return _SafeString; }
        set 
        { 
            _SafeString += ("\n" + value); 
        }
    }
```

So that 'assigning' to the string actually appends to the original, rather than just assigning.

Comment: And it is worth mentioning that you should never ever do this in real world code.

Comment: This is my theory as well, but it'd mean the assignment is pretty badly phrased.

Comment: Zoidberg is absolutely correct. Doing this with real code would be insanely confusing for developers who don't know that the SafeString property is going to do something other than assign their string.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Just FYI, this is a very small part of a huge homework assignment. I wanted to be upfront that it was part of homework because I didn't want anyone to think I was trying to trick them.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of *attribute* is more like *field* or *property* in C#. You should take a look at properties, it will allow you to execute all kinds of custom logic when a value is assigned to (or gotten from) a field.

```
private string history;
public string History
{
    get { return history; }
    set
    {
        // Do something fancy with 'value', e.g:
        history = history + "\n" + value;
    }
}
```